# Terminal: how to make tab notify somehow when new text received

Tags: macos, terminal, iterm

I'm familiar with some Terminal's, like in Linux, that have an option to "flash" or "change color" the tab's title text, whenever new text is "displayed" on that screen (for instance, tailing a file).  iTerm can do it in OS X as well splendidly, changing the font color, etc.  Is there a way to do that with the built-in mac `Terminal` application?  I'm not talking about some special "when you finish this command, flash a growl message" just a general small notification when new text is received.

Comment: Which version of OS X are you using? Terminal in Yosemite does show a little black dot in a tab that has been updated, if I remember correctly. If you have the tab bar visible.

Comment: (10.10) wow, that is tiny and didn't even notice it LOL, but it does (for instance `ssh...`.  Feel free to convert yours to an answer and I'll accept it.  Anybody know if there's a way to make it more noticable somehow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running Yosemite, you should see an ellipsis (three dots) on the extreme right side of a tab if that tab has been updated while not in the foreground. See the left-hand tab in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of Terminal showing ellipsis in background tab]

Answer (score 1):

In Yosemite, you can see three little dots on the right of the tab which has activity.

Anyway, I can highly recommend [iTerm 2](http://www.iterm2.com). In "Appearance", it has the option to "color tab labels on activity" which will make the title red. Not sure if it's even on by default.